# what am I doing wrong with this script

Tags: oracle

what is the error with my code when i run it i have this error

```
ORA-00911: caractère non valide


Create table contient(
Num_Spect varchar(30) not null,
Code_Module varchar(30) not null,
constraints pk_contient primary key (Num_Spect,Code_Module),
constraints fk_spect _t_contient FOREIGN key (Num_Spect) REFERENCES specialite(Num_Spect),
constraints fk_module _t_contient FOREIGN key (Code_Module) REFERENCES module(Code_Module));
```

Comment: Tell what this is about, what you are trying to do, where the problem sits, which exceptions you get and for sure error-messages.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes and close requests. There is a piece of code and an error message. Clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `_t_contient` from the script and try.

```
Create table contient(
Num_Spect varchar(30) not null,
Code_Module varchar(30) not null,
constraints pk_contient primary key (Num_Spect,Code_Module),
constraints fk_spect  FOREIGN key (Num_Spect) REFERENCES specialite(Num_Spect),
constraints fk_module  FOREIGN key (Code_Module) REFERENCES module(Code_Module));
```

Answer (score 0):

The word `constraints` is not valid - it should be `constraint`:

```
Create table contient
  (Num_Spect       varchar(30) not null,
   Code_Module     varchar(30) not null,
   constraint pk_contient
     primary key (Num_Spect, Code_Module),
   constraint fk_spect_t_contient
     FOREIGN key (Num_Spect) REFERENCES specialite(Num_Spect),
   constraint fk_module_t_contient
     FOREIGN key (Code_Module) REFERENCES module(Code_Module));
```

Best of luck.

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: There was a blank between `fk_spect` and `_t_conient` which I removed; likewise removed the space between `fk_module` and `_t_contient`.